# Apply mesh transformations to primitive_uv_sphere_add()

Tags: python, mesh, transforms

How can I apply mesh transformations using the Blender's `mathutils` 3D transformation matrix to a sphere formed using `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add()`

I am successfully able to construct a 3D transformtaion matrix using `mathutils.Matrix.Rotation` matrix and `mathutils.Matrix.Translation` matrix and apply the `transform()` operation on a mesh created manually using `me = bpy.data.meshes.new()` and passing it the vertices and faces/edges using `me.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)`. However, I would like to use the same transformation matrix to apply the corresponding transformations to a sphere.

Can someone point out a way to do the above; or suggest some workaround for the same?

Comment: It is always a good idea to post a working snippet where someone who could answer the question can start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by getting the mesh of the object and multiplying the transformation matrix to each vertex. (Possibly there is a convenience function for that).

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
import mathutils
from mathutils import Vector,Quaternion
import math

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]  # particular object by name
#obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.active # active object

# setup whatever matrix
mx = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(15.0), 4, 'X')

mesh = obj.data
for vert in mesh.vertices:
    vert.co = mx * vert.co
```